# Node.js: throw new Error('Can\'t set headers after they are sent.');

Tags: node.js, postgresql, restful-authentication

I keep getting this error whenever this get API is executed. I am new to node.js and I am really lost can someone please help me see what I am doing wrong?

```
app.get('/quote/:id', function(req, res) {

var results = [];
var userToken = [];

client1 = new pg.Client(connectionString);
client1.connect();
var query1 = client1.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE access_token = $1', [req.body.access_token]);
query1.on('row', function(row){userToken.push(row);});
query1.on('end', function(result) {
    client1.end();
    if(userToken.length<1){
        res.status(401).send("Unauthorized");
    }
});

client2 = new pg.Client(connectionString);
client2.connect();
var query2 = client2.query('SELECT * FROM quotes WHERE quote_id = $1', [req.params.id]);
query2.on('row', function(row){results.push(row);});
query2.on('end', function(result) {
    client2.end();
    if(results.length<1){
        return res.status(404).send({"error":"NOT FOUND"});
    }
    return res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(results));
});

});
```

Comment: You say you keep getting an error, what is the exact error that you are getting?

Comment: `can't set headers after they are sent.` Exactly , you cannot. First set headers before sending out response. Find the relevant code that does this and correct it.

Comment: I think you should put `return` before this: `res.status(401).send("Unauthorized");`

Comment: on the web browser i get this error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)" but the problem is the password i am using to sign in is correct and the token i get back is the same token that gets saved in the database.. And when i run heroku logs on terminal i get this error "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent."

Comment: @AndreyPopov i have corrected it but i still get the same error.. Abhinav it doesn't say which line the error is coming from

Comment: Oh, actually, the return won't work there. You need **stop** the client2 query if client1 returns 401. So maybe use this check again `if(userToken.length<1){` right before client2 query..

Comment: @AndreyPopov it is still throwing the error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't make calls to `res.send` multiple times. It ends the response when you do. If you need to send more data to the client then create a data object (`var data = {}`) and add everything you need to it. Then call `res.status(statusCode).send(data)` at the bottom when everything is all finished.